# How to colorize found symbols in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have a method for filter (multiple or not) data in `JTable`, here is the code:

```
public void filter() {
    if(Main.is_loading)
        return;
    RowFilter<Object, Object> serviceFilter = null;
    if (!multiple) {
        String filterText = tfield.getText();
        if (filterText.length() > 2)
            serviceFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?iu)" + filterText);
    } else {
        List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < tfields.size(); i++) {
            String filterText = "";
            JTextField cur = tfields.get(i);
            filterText = cur.getText();
            if (cur.getText().length() > 2) {
                filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?iu)" + filterText, i));
            }
        }
        serviceFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(serviceFilter);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
}
```

How do I change the color of found symbols? I need to mark matched symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter your table model to find matched cells. Then for all matched cells force repaint cell view (if you used `AbstractTableModel` call `fireTableCellUpdated(int,int)`). Also you need improve your cell renderer. When you use text filter and cell text matched, just display matched text with other color.

```
class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isFilterUsed() && isCellMatched(row, column)) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();
            String filter = getFilterValue();
            int start = stringValue.indexOf(filter);
            int end = start + filter.length();
            String result = String.format("<html>%s<font color='red'>%s</font>%s</html>",
                    stringValue.substring(0, start),
                    stringValue.substring(start, end),
                    stringValue.substring(end));

            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, result, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        } else {
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }
}
```